# Android auto - how to enable developer mode

Tags: android, android-auto

Previously in Android Auto app I could open the Auto app and tap on the header image about 10 times, then you'll get a toast message telling you that developer mode is accessible from the overflow menu. But since the update I'm not able to turn on developer mode anymore. Is there a new way to do it ?

It use to be like [this](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/03/19/android-auto-has-a-developer-mode-and-heres-how-to-enable-it/) but now the app is updated and there is still a header image but its a microphone now as shown below which does nothing when clicked:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from [androidpolice.com](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/11/04/android-auto-v1-4-cleans-up-the-companion-app-interface-and-adds-granular-control-for-previously-connected-cars-apk-download/):

> **Developer Mode**
>
> Finally, a note about developer mode, since a few people will
>   certainly ask. It's still there and accessible in basically the same
>   way. Instead of tapping several times on the lead image, you'll want
>   to give ten quick taps right on the words "Android Auto" in the action
>   bar. Just like before, a toast message will confirm that it worked.
>   But don't expect anything new in the developer options screen, it's
>   identical to the previous version.

Comment: As of the Companion app available in late 2017, these instructions are no more valid. To enable developer mode you need to enter in the About menu as described in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46484111/118862) to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Just an update for 2019, my phone is running Android Auto 4.4.592344-release and clicking on the "Android Auto" toolbar did not enable the developer settings.

Instead,

1. Open the Android Auto companion app
2. Click on the "hamburger" menu and go to Settings
3. Scroll to the bottom and click on Version

   - It expands showing the version info for relevant installed apps
4. Click on the expanded version info multiple times, eventually a toast notification pops up with a click counter, keep clicking until the developer settings are enabled

This is similar to how the developer settings are enabled in the root Android settings too.

Comment: This is the correct answer for newer versions of Android Auto. It worked for me on version 6.4.611714-release.

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide a link that supports the accepted answer, but from an official [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/auto/testing/index.html):

> On the mobile device, enable Android Auto developer mode by starting the Android Auto companion app, and then tapping the *Android Auto* toolbar title 10 times. This step is only required the first time you run the companion app.

Answer (score 1):

To enable Android Auto developer mode:
 1. Start the [Android Auto companion app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.projection.gearhead&hl=en)
 2. Open Navigation Drawer
 3. Tap About menu item
 4. Tap 10 times the top horizontal Toolbar where it says "About Android Auto"
 5. A Toast message shows up when the developer mode has been activated
 6. [Continue with the next steps - Start head unit server from the menu, etc.](https://developer.android.com/training/auto/testing/index.html#running-dhu)

Answer (score 0):

Now we can go to the about option and instead of clicking on the image go to the settings inside about page.

Tap Version 10 times to get the developer option.